# Cant open project after update Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I update android studio  and layer i can't open any project, the image is the message.

- It doesnt matter if the project use kotlin or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tu update the Kotlin plugin.
Follow this steps.

Step 1. Open the plugin options in android studio menu.
[image]

Step 2. Select Kotlin plugin and clic update.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have installed plugins which are not compatible With Android Studio. You have to uninstall them.

Please check if your Android Studio version is supported by your plugins that you have.

It looks like problem in Kotlin Plugin.